# Cursor Position relative to Application

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

I know how to get the cursor's position :

```
 int X = Cursor.Position.X;
 int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
```

But this is relative to the screen. How do i get the coordinates relative to my Form?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`Control.PointToClient` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx). Assuming `this` points to the form in question:

```
var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(X, Y));
```

Or simply:

```
var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: I used : var relativePoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position); but it stil returns the screen coordinates

Comment: Just tried it and it works for me: `var cpos = Cursor.Position; MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}\n{1}", cpos, this.PointToClient(cpos)));` gives two different points

Comment: @Mordacai1000 **it's hard to believe** what you said :)) Unless your form has no border and it's **maximized** to full screen.

Comment: i see now, but this first point is relative to the screen(as it should  be) but the second set of coordinates is -227 and -75, where it should be 0:0

Answer (score 3):

I would use `PointToClient` like this:

```
Point p = yourForm.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
//if calling it in yourForm class, just replace yourForm with this or simply remove it.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about trying like this using the **[Control.PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx)**:-

```
public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 150);
        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        panel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.panel_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel);
    }

  private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Point point = panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    MessageBox.Show(point.ToString());
  }
```