# C# Cursor position relative to application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor

I would like to have a context menu pop up, if I perform a right click somewhere on my TreeView (not the individual nodes).

This kinda works but the menu pops up way off the click position.
I tried it with this trick [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164933/cursor-position-relative-to-application) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code and a scrrenshot. Any ideas ?

```
    private void Mainform_TreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...the overload that accepts **only** a Point expects **Screen Coords**, so you simply need:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
```